# Selecting some words from a vector

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract some words from vector

```
#[1] "crossWord"       "stackedBARgraph" "crossBOW"        "topHat"         
#[5] "BowtinG"         "softH"
```

From the above list, I need to get

```
 "crossWord"  "topHat", "softH"
```

The rule is if there is a lower case letter, then one upper case letter at the end or if not at the end, then lower case letter follows and the words should not begin with upper case

Comment: Your rules confusing me...

Comment: Sorry, will try next time to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
  grep("^[a-z]+[A-Z]([a-z]+|\\b)", str1, value=TRUE)
  #[1] "crossWord" "topHat"    "softH"    

  #data
  str1 <-  c("crossWord", "stackedBARgraph", "crossBOW", "topHat", "BowtinG", "softH")
```

#### Explanation

```
`^` beginning of string 
`[a-z]+` one or more lower case characters followed by
`[A-Z]`  one uppercase character followed by
`([a-z]+|\\b)` either one ore more lower case characters or a word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regular-expression :

```
v <- c("crossWord","stackedBARgraph","crossBOW","topHat","BowtinG","softH")

validIdxs <- grep("^[a-z]+(([A-Z][a-z]+)|([A-Z]))$",v)
v[validIdxs]
# [1] "crossWord" "topHat"    "softH"
```

Regex test online : http://regex101.com/r/vW2pQ7/1